# What is the fastest way to get the longest LinkedList in a LinkedList of LinkedList?

Tags: java, list, linked-list

My data structure is a List of Lists, precisely, `LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>`

Since I have some lists, I just want to find the list which has the bigger size.
What is the fastest way?

Comment: Why wouldn't iterating the list and finding the biggest listItem.size() be the fastest?

Comment: I assume biggest means greatest number of elements (greatest number of strings), not greatest combined length of strings or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LinkedList` class in Java contains operations that you normally wouldn't have in a typical linked list. One case is being able to call `size()` on a `LinkedList` object. This is because the class inherits from the `AbstractCollection` interface. Therefore, you can just do something like this to find the biggest list:

```
int largest = -1;
LinkedList<String> largestLinkedList = null;
for (LinkedList<String> ll : listOfLinkedLists) {
    if (ll.size() > largest) {
        largestLinkedList = ll;
        largest = ll.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should initialize `largest = -1`, so that if your list of lists contains only empty lists, you actually get one of the empty lists, instead of `null`.

Comment: I wasn't aware an operation like `size` wasn't typical in other language's linked list implementations.

Comment: I'm guessing other languages implement linked lists with a size property for performance sake. But in a theoretical linked list structure, you wouldn't have access to the size of the collection. You would have to linearly iterate over each element until you hit a termination node.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate it:

```
int maxSize = listOfLists.stream().map(Collection::size).max(Integer::compare).orElse(0);
```

(Or getting the list itself)

```
List<String> max = listOfLists.stream().max((l1, l2) -> Integer.compare(l1.size(), l2.size())).orElse(null);
```

If you wanted, you could store this result and simply update it whenever you add/remove a list. Keep in mind this is a little more brittle if the lists are mutable.

Comment: Does not return which list is the longest, but what the length of the longest list is.  Not quite what the question asked.

Comment: Either one is easy to retrieve. I'll put the other one up, one moment

Comment: Close, but max( ) returns an `Optional<List<String>>`.  Add `.orElse(null)` or similar to get it to compile.

Comment: D'oh, I write these fairly quickly. Added #orElse as well.

Comment: Make it `.orElse(Collections.emptyList())` please.

Comment: @erickson Actually, `.orElseThrow(new IllegalArgumentException("No list given"))` would probably be more correct.  `.orElse(Collections.emptyList())` would return a list that is not in the original list of lists, which is clearly not correct.

Comment: There's _lots_ of ways you can do it, but it's much more semantical and up to the OP at that point, the meat of the idea is there.

Comment: @AJNeufeld Yes, in this case, `IllegalArgumentException::new` would make more sense.

Comment: @erickson My edit failed ... more than 5 minutes elapsed.  `NoSuchElementException::new`

Comment: Yes, even better!

Comment: @erickson Of course it is better.  After all, it is what `.get()` does ... returns the `Optional` if present, and throws `NoSuchElementException` otherwise.  (Face palm)

Comment: Nice keeping up with the criticizing geeks, @Rogue. I haven’t tried, but now you are being so elegant, rather than `(l1, l2) -> Integer.compare(l1.size(), l2.size())` I would expect you can do just `Comparator.comparingInt(List::size)`.